# Compiling Python 2.7 installer on Windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to compile Python 2.7 installer on Windows. The compilation works fine, but when I try to run

```
PCbuild\python.exe setup.py bdist_wininst
```

I get an error:

```
error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix that?

Update:
I found a file called `Pyconfig.h.in` in the root directory. After renaimnig it to `Pyconfig.h` bdist fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2076, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 2071, in main
    'Lib/smtpd.py']
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "Python-2.7.3\Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\command\bdist_wininst.py", line 131, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "Python-2.7.3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 152, in build_extensions
    missing = self.detect_modules()
  File "setup.py", line 1146, in detect_modules
    for arg in sysconfig.get_config_var("CONFIG_ARGS").split()]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Comment: `.in` files are usually files that need to be processed into the target filetype by some tool - autoconf typically. Are you sure you didn't miss a step that would run such a tool? What does the documentation tell you to do?

Comment: @Daenyth, if I were using Linux, I would run ./configure script, but I can't find anything similar on Windows.

Comment: ActiveState's free python download is normally quick and easy to install on Windows.  Have you tried that? (http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads)

Comment: @jcfollower I need debug version of Python, that's why I need to manually compile it.